# How to query connections/endpoints contained in a parent div

Tags: jsplumb

Is there a way to query jsPlumb in order to retrieve all connections whose "source" and "target" properties have the same parent div? Currently, I am manually setting the "scope" property of each connection (based on the parent div's id), and this works. However, feels hacky. I feel as if there should be some way to query jsPlumb like

```js
jsPlumb.select('#parentDiv').each(function(connection) {
    /*do stuff here*/
});
```

Comment: nope, there's no way. Also, the requirement is a little out of the box to be supported by `jsPlumb`, the hack is cool enough.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of connection creation itself you can check and store those connections separately instead of checking for it later. Code:

```
jsPlumb.bind("jsPlumbConnection", function(ci) {
    var s=ci.sourceId,c=ci.targetId;
    var f=$('#'+s).parent().attr("id");
    var g=$('#'+c).parent().attr("id");
    if( f===g ){
        // store ci.connection
        console.log("Connection:"+ ci.connection +" has same parent div");
    }
});
```

Comment: This looks interesting. I have moved on to another project for the moment, but will re-visit this at the end of the week.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can confined it to a specific parent div & use 'instance' for each jsPlumb operation :

```
jsPlumb.ready(function () {
    instance = jsPlumb.getInstance({
    DragOptions: { cursor: 'pointer', zIndex: 2000 },
    ConnectionOverlays: [
        ["Arrow", { width: 12, length: 15, location: -3 }],
    ],
    Container: "parent" //put parent div id here
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function containsCycle() {

    var return_content = false;
    $('.item:visible').each(function() {
        $(this).addClass("white");
    });

    $('.item:visible').each(function() {
        $vertex = $(this);
        if ($vertex.hasClass("white")) {
            if (visit($vertex)) {
                return_content = true;
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    return return_content;
}

function visit(vertex) {
    vertex.removeClass("white")
        .addClass("grey");
    var vertex_connections = jsPlumb
        .getConnections({
            source: vertex
        });

    for (var i = 0; i < vertex_connections.length; i++) {
        if ($('#' + vertex_connections[i].targetId)
            .hasClass("grey")) {
            return true;
        } else if ($('#' + vertex_connections[i].targetId)
            .hasClass("white")) {
            if (visit($('#' + vertex_connections[i].targetId))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    vertex.removeClass("grey")
        .addClass("black");
    return false;
}
```

Use this code to find the cycle connection